# how to move invaders from left to right

Tags: c#, windows

i am developing a space invader game, and i am new to this game programming thing.

i need the invaders to move from left to right.

i have 4 rows of pictureboxes,10 invaders per row.

the problem i am having is that only 1 of the rows are moving.

please help!

Thank you

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Dispose();

        objsp.gsImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\kuven\Desktop\SpaceInvader\SpaceInvader\Space Shooter.png");
        objsp.gsImage = Resized(objsp.gsImage, 2);

        objsp.gsPos = new Point(660, 650);


        Cursor.Hide();


        Cursor.Position = new Point(660 + objsp.gsImage.Width / 2, 650 + objsp.gsImage.Height / 2);
        Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);

        objsp.invader = new PictureBox[invaderrow,invadercol];

        for(int r = 0; r <= invaderrow-1; r++)
        {
            for( int c = 0; c<=invadercol-1; c++)
            {
                objsp.invader[r,c] = new PictureBox();
                objsp.invader[r,c].Image= pictureBox2.Image;
                objsp.invader[r,c].Image = Resized(pictureBox2.Image, 2);
                objsp.invader[r,c].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                objsp.invader[r,c].Location= new Point((c * 100) + 10, 10 + r * 50);
                this.Controls.Add(objsp.invader[r,c]);
            }
        }
        invadermove.Enabled = true;

    }
```

**//moving invaders**

```
private void invadermove_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r <= invaderrow-1 ; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c <= invadercol - 1; c++)
            {
                if (level == 0)
                    dir = "r";
                if (objsp.invader[r,9].Left >= ClientSize.Width)
                    dir = "l";

                if (dir == "r")
                {
                    if (c < 9)
                    {
                        objsp.invader[r,c].Location = new Point(objsp.invader[r,c].Left + 10, level * 5 + 25);
                    }

                    if (c > 8)
                    {
                        objsp.invader[r,c].Location = new Point(objsp.invader[r,c].Left + 10, level * 5 + 61);
                        if (objsp.invader[r,9].Left >= ClientSize.Width)
                        {
                            level += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (dir == "l")
                {
                    if (c < 9)
                    {
                        objsp.invader[r,c].Location = new Point(objsp.invader[r,c].Left - 10, level * 5 + 25);
                    }

                    if (c > 8)
                    {
                        objsp.invader[r,c].Location = new Point(objsp.invader[r,c].Left - 10, level * 5 + 61);
                        if (objsp.invader[r,0].Left <=0)
                        {
                            dir = "r";
                            level += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int r = 0; r <= invaderrow-1; r++)
    {
        for( int c = 0; c<=invadercol-1; c++)
        {
            objsp.invader[c] = new PictureBox();
            objsp.invader[c].Image= pictureBox2.Image;
            objsp.invader[c].Image = Resized(pictureBox2.Image, 2);
            objsp.invader[c].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            objsp.invader[c].Location= new Point((c * 100) + 10, 10 + r * 50);
            this.Controls.Add(objsp.invader[c]);
        }
    }
```

Here you are creating invaderrow times invadercol count invaders, I assume 4 and 10 respectively, but storing only in an invadercol sized array, so each iteration of the outer for loop will override the result of the previous iteration. So you won't have the references for the previous ones, only the new ones, that's why the move method only moves those for which you have the reference.
You should use maybe a [2-dimension array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (`objsp.invader[r,c]` *(corrected according to kendfrey's comment)*) or something similar.

Then in your move method make sure, to move all of the PictureBox instances.

Comment: A two-dimensional array is like this: `objsp.invader[r,c]`

Comment: @kendfrey thanks for pointing this out, actually I never used multidimensional arrays in C# before, so wasn't sure about the syntax. I will correct in my answer.

Comment: i have edited the code as you recommended but it does the same thing. only now it removes all the other rows of invaders and only moves the last row.

Comment: @KuvenRamsamy It looks like that you are positioning the 4 rows on each other, what I mean is the Y coordinate is only dependent of the level value, and not the row or the current coordinate of the PictureBox. Try something like this: invader[r, c].Location = new Point(invader[r, c].Left - 10, level * 5 + r * 50 + 25);

Comment: thanks rankep. it works but, now my invaders are running away from me ,of the screen LOL. ill try and figure it out. thanx

Comment: @KuvenRamsamy it was just an example, replace 50 with the height of the image, I think it should solve it.

Comment: no my mistake, when dir=="l" the x co-ordinate surpose to be subtracted.